# How to get the Id that is checked in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" CssClass=" checkbox-tab"  ID="chbcountry" /><%#(Eval("Description")) %>
```

and I am binding data from the database

```
 rspCountry.DataSource = countries;
 rspCountry.DataBind();
```

The check box is present in repeater control.How do I get the id of the country

Edit : Added code by the OP

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rspCountry"> 
    <ItemTemplate > 
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCountry" CssClass=" checkbox-desc" > 
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" CssClass=" checkbox-tab" ID="chbcountry" />
          <%#(Eval("Description")) %>
        </asp:Label>
        <br/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Isnt that present in your countries data source?

Comment: the is is also present in the datasource but i want the id that is selected by the user in the repeater control

Comment: You might want to add more code to illustrate that. The code you have posted does not explain your problem very well.

Comment: <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rspCountry">
                                                    <ItemTemplate >
                                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCountry" CssClass=" checkbox-desc" >
                                                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" CssClass=" checkbox-tab"  ID="chbcountry" /><%#(Eval("Description")) %></asp:Label><br/>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:Repeater>

Answer (score 0):

Please use itemcommand event to get the id which is selected.

Comment: <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rspCountry">
                                                    <ItemTemplate >
                                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCountry" CssClass=" checkbox-desc" >
                                                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" CssClass=" checkbox-tab"  ID="chbcountry" /><%#(Eval("Description")) %></asp:Label><br/>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:Repeater> this is my code can you tell me how to use itemcommand

Comment: Please refer this document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you have a field named `Id` in the DB and you want to be able to access it when a user clicks a specific `CheckBox`.
If this is the case, you can use an Attribute like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" CssClass=" checkbox-tab"  
              ID="chbcountry" InternalId=" <%#(Eval("Id")) %>" />  <%#(Eval("Description")) %>
```

Then, in the CodeBehind you can access it like this:

```
string id = chbcountry.Attributes["InternalId"]; // Returns the Id
```

Comment: string id = chbcountry.Attributes["InternalId"]; I think we need to add some thing because it is present in a repeater control

Comment: You'll have to use the **[findcontrol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)** , which EVENT do you want to access it in?